# Best route to travel among: Cologne, Copenhagen, Oslo, Stockholm

Tags: stockholm, copenhagen, cologne, oslo, scandinavia

I am planning to make a trip to Scandinavian countries from Cologne, Germany. But I am confused which route(Cologne-Norway-Sweden-Denmark-Cologne or any other order) will be most cost efficient.

My preference is to travel by train or Bus, but obviously I will have to select Air travelling sometime.

My expected travelling time: Last week of December

Can someone suggest route and medium of transport?

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: There are dozens of permutations of connections and sequences you can take, which makes your question difficult to answer; you do not specify a point which the time/cost/inconvenience tradeoff will make it worth traveling by one mode or another, nor what season you are traveling in, nor indeed any research you have attempted in the matter, for instance, by searching Rome2Rio or other search engines. Please [edit](http://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/57915/edit) your post to narrow down what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will try to provide further information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to fly, but if you are short on time it might be helpful.

From Cologne you can take a train to Copenhagen, it takes about 9 hours during the day, with just one change.
I guess there will be buses as well, likely overnight ones, as that is what I remember from older timetables. But the overnight (no change) train is no longer on the schedule.

From there you can easily travel to Sweden and from there to Norway.
I would do it in that order, as I did it the other way around and was disappointed by the tame nature of Sweden. But if you prefer culture over nature, keep Sweden or Copenhagen for last.

If the ferries between Norway and Denmark run at the time you want to travel, you can go back south that way and see mainland Denmark on the way.

Do not just to cities, in Norway you should go to west coast, the fjords. If you have enough time you might like to go north as well, see the midnight sun or northern lights depending on the time of the year.

I would not do such a travel with less than a week per country, more time will be better.

If you have only one week and that one in winter, select one location and travel there as efficiently as you can, like flying to the north of Norway to see the Northern lights. Or only Stockholm or Copenhagen.

Comment: Do you know usually when Northern light is visible in Norway?

Comment: More likely in winter than in summer but even at the best of times it is a 50 percent chance. I would not bet on them being there, the odds are not good enough. But the farther north the better the chances.